# Export nano's syntax highlighting

Tags: nano, syntax-highlighting

I like how [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) highlights bash scripts and I often use GNOME terminal's "Copy as HTML" option to copy/paste the color highlights to LibreOffice when writing documentation.  That works fine for short scripts, but kind of a pain for long script.

Is there a way to export the color highlighting with nano?  ASCII color-coded output would work as there are programs to translate that to HTML which I can import.  Or any existing syntax highlighter that has nano's color scheme?

Comment: set terminal font size to 1 ;-)

Comment: @frostschutz That's actually not a terrible idea.  Using two monitors I can copy 780 lines at a time.  Thanks for that.